# Checking cells for one of multiple data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a Script that checks the rows, wen the second all the rows on the first column are done, check the next one, and so on.

I want to remove some words from an excel table, the problem  is that there are a lot of words.

I'd like to do something like this:
`IF A1 = car OR boat OR train ...` for each cell that has text in it.
if the cell contains the specified text, to remove it.

Can anyone give some examples?

thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Does it HAS to go column by column? You could also use the Find/Replace function of Excel to find each word and replace it with "".

Comment: Not necessarily column by column. But Find/Replace isn't an option, i have about 4500 rows. And about 50 words to remove.

Comment: I meant using Find/Replace through VBA. I posted below an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Find/Replace through VBA. It is very fast.

```
Sub SearchAndDestroy()
    Dim SearchWordCell As Range

    For Each SearchWordCell In Range("A1:A50") 'Asuming that range A1:A50 is the list with the 50 words you want to search/replace

        Range("C10:R4510").Replace What:=SearchWordCell.Value, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False  'Asuming that range C10:R4510 is the table where you want to find and delete the words.

    Next SearchWordCell

End Sub
```

Just modify as needed.

Comment: how can i modify this script to remove the words that are not in the list and leave the others? thanks, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Store the list of words that you want to delete in a range and cycle through this range.

Example:

```
Sub DeleteFromWordList()
Dim InRange As Range, CritRange As Range
Dim InCell As Range, CritCell As Range

    Set InRange = Selection                  ' all selected source cells
    Set CritRange = Range("Words2Delete")    ' the named range of words to be excluded

    For Each InCell In InRange.Cells
        For Each CritCell In CritRange.Cells
            If InCell = CritCell Then
                InCell = ""                  ' blank it
                Exit For                     ' exit inner for
            End If
        Next CritCell
    Next InCell
End Sub
```

Hope that helps .... good luck MikeD

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I tried your script but i keep getting error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error. Any idea why? I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: no idea ... I am using 2003. Have you created the range "Words2Delete"? Can you cycle through with debugger and check at which statement you get the error?